# How to do text corrections with a suffix array?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We used suffix array to implement search by keywords, for example consider a phrase:

**white bathroom tile**

we insert suffixes:

1) white bathroom tile

2) bathroom tile

3) tile

and now the phrase "white bathroom tile" can be found if a user types in words: "white", "bathroom" or "tile".

However, now there's a problem, a person can type in "tyle" and nothing will be found.

So, I wanted to ask how to implement some sort of fast fuzzy search for this. Basically I want this algorithm to correct the user and still find "tile".

I considered applying levenstein distance, but my attempt failed. The idea was that we could find the group of words that start with "t" and compute levenstein distance for each one of them, and then return results where the levenstein distance was minimal.

This failed, because the user can type is "iile" instead of "tile", and now nothing words, my algorithm applies levenstein distance to the words in the "i" group.

What is a good way to solve this?

Comment: Find longest common subsequence and then suggest the word that matches the most.

Comment: so you mean you already have an algorithm in place?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, I will use BK-tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this interesting article](https://signal-to-noise.xyz/post/bk-tree/) about a data structure called [**BK-tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) and related algorithms. So, I'm considering using a BK-tree.

Also [this article](http://ntz-develop.blogspot.com/) talks about even more powerful methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Edit distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm find the list of words which have the minimum edit distance with the searched word.

For example, With the word `tyle` and `ile` the edit distance of the searched word `tile` will be 1. For the word `iile`, the edit distance between `tile` and `iile` will be 1 as well.

**Update**

If traversing all words on the suffix array and calculating edit distance is slow (it is, the edit distance is `O(^2)` in time complexity), I would suggest to build a prefix tree (trie) with all the suffixes of the sentence. And then during lookup, for example, for word `tyle`, try to traverse the prefix tree in this way:

- If there is a node in the prefix tree for the current character, traverse the node
- If there is no node for current character, recursively traverse all nodes and skip this character.
- During lookup, calculate the number of characters you skipped. The fewer number of characters you skips, the better candidate the word is.

Comment: Please, read my post more carefully, I already considered this approach.

Comment: What's the problem with `iile`? The distance will be 2 in case

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to scan through all the suffix array and compute edit distance between the search query and every entry of the suffix array.

Comment: I have also thought about this, but this will eat up way too much memory. I'm considering converting my suffix array to suffix tree and applying this approach.

Comment: Yes, the tree won't be compressed as suffix array and require a lot of memory for large dataset

Comment: Also, you haven't fully thought through your algorithm at the bottom, because in the case of "iile", I will traverse the first "i" and then what? In the case where there's a word that starts with an "i". How do I know that the first "i" is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance is better for words, in additional you could use [Cosine_similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) a measure of similarity between two non-zero vectors of an inner product space that measures the cosine of the angle between them

and for similarity sentence or paragraph, you could use [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) measure